# How to convert Pandas read excel dataframe to a list in Python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm reading a single column from an Excel file using Pandas:

```
df = pandas.read_excel(file_location, usecols=columnA)
```

and I want to convert that dataframe (df) into a list. I'm trying to do the following:

```
listA = df.values()
```

but I'm getting the following error: *TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable*. What can I do to solve this error or is there any other way I can convert that dataframe into a list? Thank you!

Comment: can you show the dataframe you are trying to convert ?

Comment: df.values.tolist()

Comment: That solution worked, thank you @Stef I didn't know there was a .tolist()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the parenthesis from your statement.  with the parens on there, it is treating values like a function.  It is an instance variable:

```
listA = df.values     # note no parenthesis after values
```

Here are a couple ideas.  You should probably access the column by name

```
In [2]: import pandas as pd                                                     

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,5,99]})                                       

In [4]: df                                                                      
Out[4]: 
    A
0   1
1   5
2  99

In [5]: df.values                                                               
Out[5]: 
array([[ 1],
       [ 5],
       [99]])

In [6]: my_list = list(df['A'])                                                 

In [7]: my_list                                                                 
Out[7]: [1, 5, 99]
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use tolist as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel(file_location, sheet_name="data")
list_data =pd.DataFrame(data,columns['C1','C2','C3','C4','C5']).values.tolist()
```